# JQuery display first 3 items and hide the rest of the results, Show all results when show more is clicked not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code where after 3rd item I want to hide the extra items until the user clicks "Show More". When Show More is clicked "Show Less" will replace the Show More and when Show Less is clicked with will again go back to display only 3 items and display "show more". Currently its adding show more for every items and not hiding the extra items.

Here is my code and [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/n7305445/51/)

```
//SHOW ONLY 2 RESULT INITIALLY ANS HIDE the REST UNTIL USER CLICKS  SHOW MORE and when SHOW LESS is clicked display show more with the 3 items. 
$("div.item-b").has("div:nth-child(5)").append('<p class="showhide">Show More</p>');
$("div.item-b").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this), $cards = $(this).closest('.item-b');
    $cards.toggleClass('open');
    $this.text($cards.hasClass('open') ? 'Show less' : 'Show more')
});
```

Comment: i do not really get it - you want the text to hide again after clicking the xx box and then you want to show it again after clicking "show more"?

Comment: @messerbill - I want to show the first 3 items initially and hide the rest. The user has to click "Show More" to see all the items and when all the item is displayed, I want to replace show More text with "Show Less"" so the user can go back to the original state of displaying just 3 items and hiding the rest of the items.

Comment: are you allowed to change "jsonObject" structure? you could add a flag to each entry "showInitial: true / false"

Comment: @messerbil -   sorry unable to change jsonObject

Answer (score 0):

i updated your fiddle - i added a counter to each element as a id

```
<div id="item_'+ID+'"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n7305445/52/

hope it helps ;)

Comment: Should "re-fork it" before positing to hide the shame.

Comment: It certainly proves the OP made some attempts at solving it themselves :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wnd01xb/). Hopefully this can help:

The basic idea is to add your "Show More" and "Show Less" divs within the list of items and then hide the "Show Less" div. These could be links or buttons also, but I decided to use divs. Use what fits your needs.

**HTML**

```
<div class="item-b">
    <div>Stuff inside 1</div>
    <div>Stuff inside 2</div>
    <div>Stuff inside 3</div>
    <div>Stuff inside 4</div>
    <div>Stuff inside 5</div>
    <div class="show more">Show More</div>
    <div class="show less">Show Less</div>
</div>
```

So next, you want to hide all the divs after the 3rd one in your list, excluding the show more/less divs, so in CSS you could do:

**CSS**

```
/* Hide the show more/less divs */
.show {
    display: none;
    color: blue;
}

.show:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide 4th div and all the ones after it */
.item-b div:nth-child(n+4) {
    display: none;
}
```

And then in your JS, you will want to apply two click handlers (you could refactor it into one click handler if you wanted to), one for the `.show.more` div and one for the `.show.less` div. This will toggle the back and forth.

Let me know if you need further clarification.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var threshold = 3;

    if ($("div.item-b").children().not(".show").length > threshold) {
        $(".show.more").css("display", "block");
    }


    $(".show.more").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().children().not(".show").css("display", "block");
        $(this).parent().find(".show.less").css("display", "block");
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $(".show.less").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().children(":nth-child(n+" + (threshold + 1) + ")").not(".show").hide();
        $(this).parent().find(".show.more").css("display", "block");
        $(this).hide();
    });

});
```